# Facebook graph API V2.0 - how to get group context? (memebers who are my friends)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Facebook major API change sucks but we have to deal with it. The page endpoint got a new "context" field which returns the number of friends who like this page, and the identity of the friends who also installed my app.

For example:

```
/v2.0/579302565453830?pretty=1&fields=context.fields(mutual_friends.limit(1000))
```

This is possible according to the new documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.0

I can also get the members of a group, for instance:

```
/v2.0/573611446041812/members
```

How can I mix it and get only the members (or at least number of members) that are my friends?
/me/friends returns only friends that use my app so this is not an option.

Comment: _“This is possible according to the new documentation”_ – no, it’s not – not for a _page_, as you are trying here. `mutual_friends` is for _user_ accounts; for pages, there is `friends_who_like` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As /v2.0/me/friends returns only app-using friends, its only possible to surface to a user the subset of a group's members, who are friends of the user, where those friends also use the app.

There is currently no `friends_who_are_members` (or similar) context edge on the Group node.

Answer (score 0):

the only way you know if someone is your friend is if that targeted someone is also using your app and granted the necessary permission.

That said, if person A is your friend and A is using your app, 'A' will come up in /me/friends and isn't the answer to your question just the overlap of the two sets?

(/v2.0/blahblah/members) ^ (/me/friends)

?

Comment: Yes this is what I currently do with API V1.0, but the new context field returns a total number of likes, for instance:
`{
  "context": {
    "mutual_friends": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "id-of-friend-who-installed-my-app",
          "name": "name-of-friend-who-intalled-my-app"
        },
        ...
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "NTI1NTYyNTU2",
          "after": "MTAwMDAxODQ0NjEyNDEz"
        }
      },
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 91
      }
    }
  }, `

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that now the /me/friends doesn't return the list of all of my friends, there's no possible way to calculate my friends out of the members of a group.
I opened a bug in Facebook, hopefully the'll fix this issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/806713822672235/